# How to convert array to associative array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my array format:

```
$data=["error.png","invoice_1.pdf","invoice2.png"];
```

But I want to this format:

```
$data=[{"file":"error.png"},{"file":"invoice_1.pdf"},{"file":"invoice2.png"}]
```

Thank you.

Comment: why would you want to give the same key to all variables ?

Comment: This really is very simple logic. You've made no attempt to do this yourself & evidently not even searched for what you wanted, because you're most definitely not this first to want to do this simple thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new array.

And loop through your existing array.

Its every element will be an array with a value from your array as value.

And key as the string `file`.

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($data as $elem) {
  $arr[] = array('file' => $elem);
}
```

Try debugging if you get the correct array:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Lastly,

```
echo json_encode($arr);
exit;
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$data = array_map(
    function ($item) {
        return array('file' => $item);
    },
    $data
);
```

to embed the values into arrays, or

```
$data = array_map(
    function ($item) {
        $x = new stdClass();
        $x->file = $item;
        return $x;
    },
    $data
);
```

to embed them into objects.

Or, better, use your own class instead of stdClass() and pass $item as argument to its constructor

```
$data = array_map(
    function ($item) {
        return new MyClass($item);
    },
    $data
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = ["error.png", "invoice_1.pdf", "invoice2.png"];
$newarray = array();
foreach ($data as $val){
    array_push($newarray, array("file" => $val));
}
print_r($newarray); //Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => error.png ) [1] => Array ( [file] => invoice_1.pdf ) [2] => Array ( [file] => invoice2.png ) )
echo json_encode($newarray); // [{"file":"error.png"},{"file":"invoice_1.pdf"},{"file":"invoice2.png"}]
exit;
```

Just try this logic

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = '["error.png","invoice_1.pdf","invoice2.png"]';
$data = json_decode($data);
$data = array_filter($data, function(&$item){return ($item = array('file' => $item));});
$data = json_encode($data);
```